# foreach statement cannot operate on variables MVC3 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the definition of CourseRegisterModel:

```
public class CourseRegisterModel
{
    public StudentModel Student { get; set; }

    public CourseModel Course { get; set; }

    public CourseModel Course1 { get; set; }
    public CourseModel Course2 { get; set; }
    public CourseModel Course3 { get; set; }
    public CourseModel Course4 { get; set; }
    public CourseModel Course5 { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CoursesList { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller function which executes on Home Page load:

```
public ActionResult Home()
    {
        //Retrieve all registered courses for this bloody student

        ServiceCourseClient client = new ServiceCourseClient();
        Course[] coursespending;
        var loggedInRollNumber = Request.Cookies["RollNumber"].Value;
        coursespending = client.GetPendingRegisteredCourses(loggedInRollNumber.ToString());
        List<CourseRegisterModel> coursesRegisteredmodelList = new List<CourseRegisterModel>();
        CourseRegisterModel CRM = null;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var serviceCourseRegistered in coursespending)
        {
            CRM = new CourseRegisterModel();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                CRM.Course1.Code = serviceCourseRegistered.Code;
                CRM.Course1.Name = serviceCourseRegistered.Name;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                CRM.Course2.Code = serviceCourseRegistered.Code;
                CRM.Course2.Name = serviceCourseRegistered.Name;
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                CRM.Course3.Code = serviceCourseRegistered.Code;
                CRM.Course3.Name = serviceCourseRegistered.Name;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                CRM.Course4.Code = serviceCourseRegistered.Code;
                CRM.Course4.Name = serviceCourseRegistered.Name;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                CRM.Course5.Code = serviceCourseRegistered.Code;
                CRM.Course5.Name = serviceCourseRegistered.Name;
            }
            i++;
            coursesRegisteredmodelList.Add(CRM);
        }

        return View(coursesRegisteredmodelList);
    }
```

And here is the view on which i am trying to display registered courses:

```
@model StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome Student";
}

<h2>Welcome 
@Context.User.Identity.Name
</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("[Sign Out]", "SignOut", "Student")
<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register Courses", "registerCourses", "Course")</li>
</ul>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        RollNumber
    </th>
    <th>
        Course Code
    </th>
    <th>
        Course Name
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Context.User.Identity.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

But foreach loop on above view is giving following compile time error:
`foreach statement cannot operate on variables type CourseRegistrationModel beacuse it does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator`

Please help.

Comment: That's strange, because you should have gotten an error that your model type does not match the model passed in, since you pass in a list of CoureseRegistrationModel but your view takes a single type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your model needs to be an `IEnumerable`. See below.

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome Student";
}

<h2>Welcome 
@Context.User.Identity.Name
</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("[Sign Out]", "SignOut", "Student")
<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register Courses", "registerCourses", "Course")</li>
</ul>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        RollNumber
    </th>
    <th>
        Course Code
    </th>
    <th>
        Course Name
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Context.User.Identity.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

You were trying to do

```
foreach(CourseRegisterModel item in CourseRegisterModel)
{
    ...
}
```

which is not possible, you want.

```
foreach(CourseRegisterModel item in IEnumerable<CourseRegisterModel>)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your Model a `List` or `IEnumerable`.  You simply pass down the class which does not implement `GetEnumerator`, it should be:

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel>
```

Or:

```
@model List<StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view model is a single object as shown here:

```
@model StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel
```

you may be wanting to iterate over the CoursesList property in your foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CoursesList) { .... }
```